# How to use a custom colormap with irregular intervals?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'm trying to use a custom colorbar in matplotlib with irregular intervals.
But when following the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html) and using the colorbar, it gets used as a regular interval colorbar.

How do I construct/use a colorbar with irregular intervals?

*MWE below:*

I'm plotting various data with `plt.matshow()`, like this:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame([
    (7, 7.1, 8 , 9),
    (0, 1, 1.5, 2),
    (2.001, 3, 3.5, 4),
    (4.001, 5, 6, 6.9999),
], index=[0, 1, 2, 3], columns=('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),)
```

and

```
plt.matshow(testdf)
```

[image: default matrix]

However, I want only certain numbers highlighted and I want to group others, i.e. I want a discrete, custom colorbar, instead of the default continuous one.

Luckily, the matplotlib documentation [has just what I need](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html).
So, lets set up this colorbar:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)

cmap = (mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan'])
        .with_extremes(over='0.25', under='0.75'))

bounds = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    cax=ax,
    boundaries=[0] + bounds + [13],  # Adding values for extensions.
    extend='both',
    ticks=bounds,
    spacing='proportional',
    orientation='horizontal',
    label='Discrete intervals, some other units',
)
```

[image: custom colorbar]

Looks great! Numbers from 1 to 2 in red and 7 to 8 in blue and two large groups for all the uninteresting stuff between 2 and 7.

So, let's use it.

```
plt.matshow(testdf, cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: custom matrix]

...and that's not what I expected.
The colorbar should look like the one I just constructed before, not regularly spaced and thus lines 0 and 1 should contain a black/grey box for over/under, line 2 should be all green and line 3 all blue.

How do I fix this? What am I missing?

Comment: You need to pass the boundary norm to `matshow` as well as the colormap so Matplotlib knows how to map your data to the colormap.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow

Comment: To *"use it"*: `plt.matshow(testdf, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)`

Comment: That works. I knew it was probably a stupid oversight. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jody Klymak and JohanC have pointed out in the comments, `norm` also needs to be passed into `matshow`, i.e. `plt.matshow(testdf, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)`.

However, this doesn't work for stuff where I can't pass further arguments with my colormap (or where I can't figure out how to do so…), e.g. in `sns.clustermap`.

A possible workaround is to define a colormap with regular intervals, with many following intervals being of the same color:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 1))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.5)

cmap = (mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['red',
                                   'green', 'green',
                                   'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue',
                                   'cyan'])
                                   .with_extremes(over='0.25', under='0.75'))

bounds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
fig.colorbar(
    mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm),
    cax=ax,
    boundaries=[0] + bounds + [13],  # Adding values for extensions.
    extend='both',
    ticks=bounds,
    spacing='proportional',
    orientation='horizontal',
    label='Discrete intervals, some other units',
)
```

Results in

[image: Colorbar]

and following that

[image: matrix]

As you can see, it's still different from what I expected in the question, but turns out that the limits are different from what I expected them to be, i.e. the interval `1, 2` means `>1, <2`which is easily fixable, if you know/expect this behaviour.